# How to get class name of draggable element?

Tags: jquery-ui

Within the droppable function how can I get the draggable element's class name which is currently being dragged.

```
$( ".drop" ).droppable( { accept: handleFunction } );
function handleFunction(draggable){
//How to get currently dragging element's class name
}
```

Comment: please give me a solution.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have you tried?

Comment: draggable.className and something else. And I don't know so I've asked just to get the class name. I searched about 3 hours but couldn't find.

Comment: can you tell me please, how can I get the class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you've got the `accept` option's usage correctly. It does not get the draggable currently being dragged, it tests the draggable that you just dropped in the `droppable` element. From [the droppable documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept):

```
Function: A function that will be called for each draggable
on the page (passed as the first argument to the function).
The function must return true if the draggable should be accepted.
```

Regardless, what you get as a parameter is a jQuery element, not a JS object. You can test its classes in several ways:

```
$( ".drop" ).droppable( { accept: handleFunction } );
function handleFunction(draggable){
     // This will return ALL classes attached to this draggable element as a string
     // This is probably NOT what you need; it's VERY fragile
     var className = $(draggable).attr('class');

     // This returns a boolean for testing if myClass is present in the element's classes
     // This is a very common function and probably what you want
     var test = $(draggable).hasClass('myClass');

     // Note return value should be a boolean.
     return test;
}
```